# Шаблон кластера в яндекс картах api 2.1

Tags: yandex-maps-api, кластер

Уже замучался с поиском...

Ни одного исполнителя на фрилансе не нашел для выполнения этой задачи, а хотя публиковал задачу раза 3 за 2 недели. 
Нужно создать полностью пользовательский шаблон кластера в яндекс картах.

В идеале - в таком формате:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите варианты как это сделать. Поиск в гугле результатов не дал. В большинстве случаев примеры не подходят или-же не имеют комментариев, чтобы разобраться в них....

Comment: Вы свой вопрос уже решили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В песочнице есть замечательный пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/cluster_custom_balloon_content_layout
В нем нужно только поменять верстку и добавить необходимые поля.

Comment: ааааа!) Спасибо! ) Я его неделю назад видел и потерял!)

Comment: А можете еще подсказать как в clusterBalloonLayout указать контент от clusterBalloonContentLayout ?

Comment: Разобрался. 
$[[options.contentLayout ]]